# How to set default theme to custom dialog box?

Tags: android, dialog, themes

I'm trying to set a default theme to a custom dialog box but unable to do it. I have set the default "THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT" to my alertDialogs and I want to use the same theme to my custom dialog box.

I am able to set other themes using the below code but I am unable to use DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT.

new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.MyTheme);

```
   public static Dialog createSeatAssignmentDialog(final Context context, final SeatAssignmentCallback callback) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.assign_seat_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.assign_seat_dialog_title);
            dialog.setOnKeyListener(DIALOG_ON_KEY_LISTENER);
            new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog);
            final EditText seat = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.seat_data);
            final Button clearSeatData = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.clear_seat_data);
            final Button assignSeat = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.assign_seat);
            final Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_seat);
            seat.setText(callback.getSeatNumber());
            clearSeatData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    seat.setText("");
                }
            });
            assignSeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            final SeatDialogHandler dialogEventHandler = new SeatDialogHandler(callback, seat);
            dialog.setOnCancelListener(dialogEventHandler);
            dialog.setOnDismissListener(dialogEventHandler);
            dialog.setOnShowListener(dialogEventHandler);
            dialog.show();
            return dialog;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

*use like this*

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light);
```